# HDD is read-only, inspite of having read-write permissions to all user and groups

Tags: mount, read-only

There are two HDDs in my system and I wish to format HDD1, which has little data.  When I tried to move that data in HDD1 to HDD2, got an error message saying "destination is read-only".  But on checking the permissions for HDD2 with 'ls -l' command, it has rwx permission for all three u,g,o.  What could be happening?
Ive already tried solutions like 'killall nautilus' and 'remount, rw', but none of them worked. Is there any other way I can remove the read-only property of HDD2?

Comment: You typically do not copy files to "hdd2" but to a directory in a mounted filesystem that resides on a hard disk. SO you would have to be more explicit about the filesystems (relevant lines in `mount` output).

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1265516/edit) to show us exactly how you are checking permissions and exactly how you are attempting to move the files.

Comment: https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld is a `bash` script that will show permissions, mount status, etc.